# Tags input is not working when I paste the files

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap TagsInput with Bootstrap Typeahead. When I try to paste the file contains ',' its working fine but when I use the file like

```
apple
banana
mango
grape
```

or

```
apple    banana    mango    grape
```

it's not working(it's not forming chip) but it should form a chip like below
[image]

is there any way to accomplish this?